# Trouble trying to install tidyverse (cluster slurm)

Tags: r, slurm, install.packages

I have have some trouble installing tidyverse in R in a node in a cluster (with Slurm).

I have tried installing broom, since for some others on the web this was necessary. I cannot install zeal

```
install.packages("tidyverse", lib = "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0")
```

This is the message I get:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp5oEAEI/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidyverse", lib = "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0") :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidyverse", lib = "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0") :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tidyverse", lib = "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0") :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("tidyverse", lib = "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0") :
  installation of package ‘dtplyr’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("tidyverse", lib = "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0") :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("tidyverse", lib = "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0") :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
```

I also cannot install 'zealot' which was posted as an answer to a similar question a year ago.

```
Selection: 54
Warning message:
package ‘zealot’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

And I've tried this as well, which also doesn't work:

```
library(tidyverse, lib.loc = "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0")
```

Could anyone help me with this or link me to a document online? I've looked a lot and also on SO.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you're running `install.packages` as part of a SLURM job? And if so, why?

Comment: I'm running it in R in a SLURM job, to analyze a very large dataset. Edit: should I do this differently?

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not have to reinstall the package every time you run a job. I would try to install the package via an interactive node instead. This is because `install.packages` will prompt some questions to the user that may not be properly addressed when running it via the queue. Can you give that a shot?

Comment: I get the exact same message as written above when trying the interactive node. I think before I used a regular node (or is every node interactive?) and now I added ```-i``` to the end.